# Using rmarkdown to create headers from a large .txt input

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a PDF with headers from rmarkdown. I'm reading in a large text file, and I want to print out this PDF using headers. I can easily read in and print to the PDF with desired formatting, minus the headers, using

````
```{r comment='', echo=FALSE}
cat(readLines("blah.txt", encoding="UTF-8"), sep="/n")
```
````

However, I can't get rmarkdown to evaluate '#' in my text, which creates headers. I've inserted the '#' into different sections of the .txt file where I want to create a header, but it doesn't evaluate the hashtag.

Does anyone know how to get rmarkdown to evaluate the '#' as a header without messing up the formatting of the text file as I already have it?

Answer (score 0):

RMarkdown recognizes `# ...`-headers only if there is an empty line before. So what you need is simply to use one more line-break `\n` (note the *back*-slashes).

````
```{r comment='', echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat(readLines("blah.txt", encoding="UTF-8"), sep="\n\n")
```
````

Note, that you may want to add `results='asis'` in the R-junk.